# Approaching an integral with the Simpson type

Tags: numerical-methods, approximate-integration, simpsons-rule

Lets say $f(x) = e^x$ and we approach the integral $$\int_a^b f(x)\, dx$$ with the Simpson type $$Q(f)=(b-a)/6{f(a)+4f((a+b)/2)+f(b)}$$

how can i prove that: $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx < Q(f)$?

(also  $a,b$ belong to $\Bbb R$, $a < b$, and $f$ belongs to $C^4[a,b]$ )

Comment: What do you know about the error term of the Simpson formula?

Comment: @LutzL the error of approximation is (1/90)(b-a/2)^5 |f^4(ξ)|

Comment: You can also get a signed error formula, i.e., the exact error. Then the sign of the 4th derivative will show the relation to the exact integral.